# Why is class variable's value 'nil' in ruby?

Tags: ruby

The following ruby script:

```
require 'pp'
class BB
    @@member = [100, 200]

    class << self
        attr_accessor :member
    end

    def setm(m)
        self.class.member = m
    end

    def setm2(m)
        @@member = m
    end

    def look(i)
        pp "ites was : #{@@member[i]}"
    end
end

pp BB.member     # nil, Why not [100, 200]?
t = BB.new
t.look 0         # item was: 100
t.look 1         # item was: 200
t.setm [200, 300]
pp BB.member     # [200, 300]

t.setm2 [400,500]
pp BB.member     # [200 , 300]  , Why not [400,500]
```

I ran it. The output is:

```
$ ruby t.rb
nil
"ites was : 100"
"ites was : 200"
[200, 300]
[200, 300]
```

Why is the output of the first `pp BB.member` `nil`, and not `[100, 200]`? And why is the last `pp BB.member` `[200, 300]`, and not `[400, 500]`?

Comment: At first glance, `BB.member #=> @member` not `@@member`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically this:

```
class << self
    attr_accessor :member
end
```

does not create a reader/writer for `@@member` as you expect but rather `@member` on the class level.

Classes are instances (of Class) and so they have instance variables too.

`@@` variables are a special thing - a variable that can be accessed from both the class and instance scope (and also shared through the iheritance chain) - and are not the same as the class's instance variables.

If you want a reader/writer for the class variable you either have to write it by hand (e.g. `def member` and `def member=(val)` in the `class << self` block), or if you `require 'active_support/all'` you can use:

```
class Foo
  cattr_accessor :member
end
```

In this case calling `@@member =` from an instance method or calling `Foo.member =` modify the same value.

Comment: the last part of your answer is rails specific and not available in core ruby and is also deprecated in class definition in new rails see  https://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor

Comment: Answer states the required library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in what you are doing. One is a class variable, and the other is an instance variable of the singleton class.

Not sure exactly what behavior you are trying to achieve, but see if something similar to the following idiom works.

```
  class Foo

    class << self
      @@bar = :bar
      def bar
        @@bar
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: your code works. when pp Foo.bar, it will output :bar.

Comment: Yeah, set the value to whatever you want. I just used a symbol in the example.